# Customize taskbar icon

Tags: unity, gnome, icons

Here is my Ubuntu installation:

[image]

I'd like to replace that sticky-note icon in the taskbar with that tomboy.svg you can see in the explorer window.

However, upon opening `/usr/share/applications/indicator-stickynote.desktop`, I cannot find an entry that pertains to the taskbar icon:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Indicator Stickynotes
Name[en_GB]=Indicator Stickynotes
Name[eu]=Ohar itsaskorren jakinarazlea
Name[uk]=Нотатки
GenericName=Sticky Notes
GenericName[ca]=Notes adhesives
GenericName[cs]=Lepící poznámky
GenericName[da]=Post-It noter
GenericName[de]=Klebezettel
GenericName[el]=Sticky Notes
GenericName[en_GB]=Sticky Notes
GenericName[es]=Notas adhesivas
GenericName[eu]=Ohar itsaskorrak
GenericName[fr]=Pense-bêtes
GenericName[he]=פתקים נצמדים
GenericName[hi]=स्टिकी नोट्स
GenericName[hr]=Ljepljive bilješke
GenericName[hu]=Ragadós jegyzetek
GenericName[it]=Note adesive
GenericName[lt]=Lipnūs rašteliai
GenericName[pt]=Sticky Notes
GenericName[pt_BR]=Notas adesivas
GenericName[ru]=Sticky Notes
GenericName[sk]=Sticky Notes
GenericName[tr]=Yapışkan Notlar
GenericName[uk]=Липкі нотатки
GenericName[zh_CN]=
GenericName[zh_TW]=
Comment=Write reminders on notes
Comment[eu]=Idatzi gogorarazleak oharretan
Comment[uk]=Запишіть нагадування в нотатках
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Ozon/scalable/apps/xpad.svg
Exec=indicator-stickynotes
Categories=Utility;TextTools;
Hidden=False
X-GNOME-autostart-enabled=true
```

As you can see, I've changed the `Icon` entry to the correct path (`/usr/share/icons/Ozon/scalable/apps/xpad.svg`), but that only changes the launcher icon. **How do I change the taskbar icon?**

To be honest, I don't like any of those task bar icons. The one on the far right should be an ubuntu logo, the speaker icon (on the left of the date) is a blank rectangle (possibly a broken path?) and the battery and networking icons could be slicker. If I could change the battery to that `unity-power-panel.svg` image I'd be happy. How can I change these taskbar icons to any svg I want?

Also, it's worth noting that when I connect, the networking icon changes to a swirling animation, the battery icon has a percentage next to it, and when I get a new email the thunderbird icon has a yellow glow effect around it.

So how should I change these icons and keep this behaviour? I'm not asking for step by step guides on these specific (though not esoteric) icons, I just want to know the general steps behind changing these icons, with respect to the fact that they are "dynamic" and not just images.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the author of the application you referenced.

The taskbar icon (nowadays referred to as "indicator" in the Ubuntu world), is set within the code itself. The application tries to pull a generic "indicator-stickynotes.png" icon file. The system usually searches for this in the current icon theme or (if that fails) in the hi-color theme. You will notice that PPA package installs a monochrome icon in ubuntu-mono-*, and a multicolor icon in hi-color.

If you don't like the icon, you can either change the source code or replace the icon.

If you do either, you might prefer forking the git repository so you can merge your changes with any changes in the upstream code.

I believe the other effects you are describing are achieve by changing the icon, but I am not sure. You will want to read about Ubuntu indicators for that.